# What wrong with Dictionary in property of class?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

Why is this code not working?

```
public class A   
{
   public Dictionary<int, string> dic { get; set; }   
}

class Program   
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.dic.Add(1, "a");
    }   
}
```

Error:
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to help you format the code better next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't initialized the property, so the value of `a.dic` is null (the default for any reference type).

You'd need something like:

```
a.dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

... or you could initialize it in the constructor.

On the other hand, it's rarely a good idea to have such direct access to the inner workings of a class - you basically have no encapsulation here.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is a reference type. It's default value is null. There's no "new Dictionary" anywhere in your program; there probably should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class A
    { public Dictionary dic;

A()

{

dic = new Dictionary();
}

    }

    class Program
    { public static void Main() { A a = new A(); a.dic.Add(1, "a");

    }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of A to something like this:

```
public class A
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> dic { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }
}
```

The key point is that you need to initialize the "dic" property before you can use it.